# Why am I unable to perform a calculation for the position in a sceneEvent for a QGraphicsObject?

Tags: qt, touch, multi-touch, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene

I have implemented QGraphicsObject with QTouchEvents and reimplemented the sceneEvent function.

```
bool LynxItem::sceneEvent(QEvent *event)
{
    //qDebug() << "LynxItem::sceneEvent:" << itemId;
    switch (event->type()) {
    case QEvent::Gesture:
    {
         qDebug() << "LynxItem::sceneEvent:Gesture" << itemId;
         return gestureEvent(static_cast<QGestureEvent*>(event));
         break;
    }
    case QEvent::TouchBegin:
    case QEvent::TouchUpdate:
    case QEvent::TouchEnd:
    {
        qDebug() << "LynxItem::sceneEvent:TouchUpdate" << itemId;
        QTouchEvent *touchEvent = static_cast<QTouchEvent *>(event);
        QList<QTouchEvent::TouchPoint> touchPoints = touchEvent->touchPoints();
        const QTouchEvent::TouchPoint &touchPoint1 = touchPoints.last();
        /* This doesn't allow two objects to move at the same time */
        //setPos ( touchPoint1.scenePos() - touchPoint1.pos());
        /* This does work but the item is always moved from top left */
        setPos(touchPoint1.scenePos());
        event->accept();
        break;
    }
    default:
        return QGraphicsItem::sceneEvent(event);;
    }
    return true;
}
```

My problem is that when I touch the item the items top right corner comes to the touch point.  I want to offset the point inside where I touched.  However when I do that I can only move one item at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question:

```
setPos ( touchPoint1.scenePos() - touchPoint1.pos());
```

Is incorrect.  On the TouchBegin I should store touchPoint1.pos():

```
m_TouchOffset = touchPoint1.pos();
```

Then use that first position instead

```
setPos ( touchPoint1.scenePos() - m_TouchOffset);
```